# How to copy a sheet between Excel workbooks in Java

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

How can I copy a sheet between two different workbooks in Apache poi?

The method is missing referring [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-another) thread. There is not such a solution.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

After a researching and trying, here my solution. I was tested with java 1.6 and apache-poi 3.8

here i wan't to provide the solution worked for me, special in this case, i pas a worksheet and a List of input streams (different workbooks i want to merge).

My solution is a merged one, i've got merged the whole sourcecode from [here](http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-another) i want to share this code with everyone, stuck on the same problem.

```
/**
* Original version available from:
* http://www.coderanch.com/t/420958/open-source/Copying-sheet-excel-file-another
**/
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;

public class CopySheets {

public Workbook mergeExcelFiles(Workbook book, List<InputStream> inList) throws IOException {

    for (InputStream fin : inList) {
        Workbook b = WorkbookFactory.create(fin);
        for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            // not entering sheet name, because of duplicated names
            copySheets(book.createSheet(),b.getSheetAt(i));
        }
    }
    return book;
}

/** 
 * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy. 
 * @param sheet the sheet to copy. 
 */  
public static void copySheets(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet){     
    copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);     
}     

/** 
 * @param newSheet the sheet to create from the copy. 
 * @param sheet the sheet to copy. 
 * @param copyStyle true copy the style. 
 */  
public static void copySheets(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){     
    int maxColumnNum = 0;     
    Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, CellStyle>() : null;     
    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {     
        Row srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);     
        Row destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);     
        if (srcRow != null) {     
            copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);     
            if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {     
                maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();     
            }     
        }     
    }     
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {     
        newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));     
    }     
}     

/** 
 * @param srcSheet the sheet to copy. 
 * @param destSheet the sheet to create. 
 * @param srcRow the row to copy. 
 * @param destRow the row to create. 
 * @param styleMap - 
 */  
public static void copyRow(Sheet srcSheet, Sheet destSheet, Row srcRow, Row destRow, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {     
    // manage a list of merged zone in order to not insert two times a merged zone  
  Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddressWrapper>();     
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());     
    // reckoning delta rows  
    int deltaRows = destRow.getRowNum()-srcRow.getRowNum();  
    // pour chaque row  
    for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {     
        Cell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);   // ancienne cell  
        Cell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);  // new cell   
        if (oldCell != null) {     
            if (newCell == null) {     
                newCell = destRow.createCell(j);     
            }     
            // copy chaque cell  
            copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);     
            // copy les informations de fusion entre les cellules  
            //System.out.println("row num: " + srcRow.getRowNum() + " , col: " + (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());  
            CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());     

            if (mergedRegion != null) {   
              //System.out.println("Selected merged region: " + mergedRegion.toString());  
              CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow()+deltaRows, mergedRegion.getLastRow()+deltaRows, mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(),  mergedRegion.getLastColumn());  
                //System.out.println("New merged region: " + newMergedRegion.toString());  
                CellRangeAddressWrapper wrapper = new CellRangeAddressWrapper(newMergedRegion);  
                if (isNewMergedRegion(wrapper, mergedRegions)) {  
                    mergedRegions.add(wrapper);  
                    destSheet.addMergedRegion(wrapper.range);     
                }     
            }     
        }     
    }                
}    

/** 
 * @param oldCell 
 * @param newCell 
 * @param styleMap 
 */  
public static void copyCell(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {     
    if(styleMap != null) {     
        if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){     
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
        } else{     
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();     
            CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);     
            if(newCellStyle == null){     
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();     
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);     
            }     
            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);     
        }     
    }     
    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {     
        case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());     
            break;     
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());     
            break;     
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:     
            newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);     
            break;     
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:     
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());     
            break;     
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:     
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());     
            break;     
      case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:     
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());     
            break;     
      default:     
            break;     
    }     

}     

/** 
 * Récupère les informations de fusion des cellules dans la sheet source pour les appliquer 
 * à la sheet destination... 
 * Récupère toutes les zones merged dans la sheet source et regarde pour chacune d'elle si 
 * elle se trouve dans la current row que nous traitons. 
 * Si oui, retourne l'objet CellRangeAddress. 
 *  
 * @param sheet the sheet containing the data. 
 * @param rowNum the num of the row to copy. 
 * @param cellNum the num of the cell to copy. 
 * @return the CellRangeAddress created. 
 */  
public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {     
    for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {   
        CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);     
        if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {     
            return merged;     
        }     
    }     
    return null;     
}     

/** 
 * Check that the merged region has been created in the destination sheet. 
 * @param newMergedRegion the merged region to copy or not in the destination sheet. 
 * @param mergedRegions the list containing all the merged region. 
 * @return true if the merged region is already in the list or not. 
 */  
private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddressWrapper newMergedRegion, Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions) {  
  return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);     
}     

}
class CellRangeAddressWrapper implements Comparable<CellRangeAddressWrapper> {  

public CellRangeAddress range;  

/** 
 * @param theRange the CellRangeAddress object to wrap. 
 */  
public CellRangeAddressWrapper(CellRangeAddress theRange) {  
      this.range = theRange;  
}  

/** 
 * @param o the object to compare. 
 * @return -1 the current instance is prior to the object in parameter, 0: equal, 1: after... 
 */  
public int compareTo(CellRangeAddressWrapper o) {  

            if (range.getFirstColumn() < o.range.getFirstColumn()  
                        && range.getFirstRow() < o.range.getFirstRow()) {  
                  return -1;  
            } else if (range.getFirstColumn() == o.range.getFirstColumn()  
                        && range.getFirstRow() == o.range.getFirstRow()) {  
                  return 0;  
            } else {  
                  return 1;  
            }  

}  

}
```

Comment: Any chance you could change this from being `HSSF` specific to handling both HSSF and XSSF? Mostly it's just swapping from `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFFoo` to `org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Foo` and using `WorkbookFactory`

Comment: Also you need to move `Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions` instantiation from `copyRow` to `copySheets` - one merged region can span multiple rows, and without that change code fails adding same merged region multiple times

Comment: Also `compareTo` is incorrect, consider ranges (A1:A3) and (C1:E1). Both have same first row, different first column. This code will return 1 no matter what order you pass ranges in.

Comment: Didn't you have a problem with `newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());`? You'll get an error: Can only clone from one XSSFCellStyle to another, not between HSSFCellStyle and XSSFCellStyle with that.

Comment: Excellent.. With a few changes to CellType and MegedRegion.. I was even able to copy excel sheet with POI 4.1.1.. Thanks !!!