# Merging Two excel files as two sheets in one workbook in java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I have two xlsx files at folder C:\DemoFilesExcel\demo1.xlsx and C:\DemoFilesExcel\demo2.xlsx.

I want to create a new xlsx  C:\DemoFilesExcel\merged.xlsx that will have these two files as two sheets in merged.xlsx workbook.

This is to be done using apache POI in java. Any idea how to do

Comment: Iterate one sheet row and add in another.I dnt thnk any method exist in POI to merge sheets..

Answer (score 4):

This below piece of code can be used to merge two excel files as two sheets in one workbook in java. This will copy both the excel files with the same structure.

It has worked for me.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;

public class MergeMultipleXlsFilesInDifferentSheet{
 public static void mergeExcelFiles(File file) throws IOException {
    HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
    System.out.println(file.getName());
    String directoryName = "C:\\MergingXlsDirectory";
    File directory = new File(directoryName);
    //get all the files from a directory
    File[] fList = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file1 : fList){
        if (file1.isFile()){
            String ParticularFile = file1.getName();
       FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(new File(directoryName+"\\"+ParticularFile));
      HSSFWorkbook b = new HSSFWorkbook(fin);
      for (int i = 0; i < b.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
          HSSFSheet sheet = book.createSheet(b.getSheetName(i));
        copySheets(book, sheet, b.getSheetAt(i));
        System.out.println("Copying..");
      }
    }
    try {
      writeFile(book, file);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
  }
  protected static void writeFile(HSSFWorkbook book, File file) throws Exception {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    book.write(out);
    out.close();
  }
  private static void copySheets(HSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet){     
    copySheets(newWorkbook, newSheet, sheet, true);
  }     

  private static void copySheets(HSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, HSSFSheet newSheet, HSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){     
    int newRownumber = newSheet.getLastRowNum();
    int maxColumnNum = 0;     
    Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, HSSFCellStyle>() : null;    

    for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {     
      HSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);     
      HSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i + newRownumber);     
      if (srcRow != null) {     
        copyRow(newWorkbook, sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);     
        if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {     
            maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();     
        }     
      }     
    }     
    for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {     
      newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));     
    }     
  }     

  public static void copyRow(HSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, HSSFSheet srcSheet, HSSFSheet destSheet, HSSFRow srcRow, HSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {     
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
    for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {     
      HSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
      HSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);
      if (oldCell != null) {     
        if (newCell == null) {     
          newCell = destRow.createCell(j);     
        }     
        copyCell(newWorkbook, oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
      }     
    }                
  }

  public static void copyCell(HSSFWorkbook newWorkbook, HSSFCell oldCell, HSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {      
    if(styleMap != null) {     
      int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();     
      HSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);     
      if(newCellStyle == null){     
        newCellStyle = newWorkbook.createCellStyle();     
        newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());     
        styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);     
      }     
      newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);   
    }     
    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getRichStringCellValue());     
        break;     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());     
        break;     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:     
        newCell.setCellType(HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);     
        break;     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:     
        newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());     
        break;     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:     
        newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());     
        break;     
      case HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:     
        newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());     
        break;     
      default:     
        break;     
    }
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      try {
        mergeExcelFiles(new File("C:\\NewXlsfileWhereDataWillBeMerged.xls"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Some context around what worked and why would help understand your answer better.

Answer (score 3):

```
//Open the first excel file.
Workbook SourceBook1 = new Workbook("F:\\Downloads\\charts.xlsx");

//Define the second source book.
//Open the second excel file.
Workbook SourceBook2 = new Workbook("F:\\Downloads\\picture.xlsx");

//Combining the two workbooks
SourceBook1.combine(SourceBook2);

//Save the target book file.
SourceBook1.save("F:\\Downloads\\combined.xlsx");
```

http://www.aspose.com/docs/display/cellsjava/Combine+Multiple+Workbooks+into+a+Single+Workbook

Comment: This is commercial library. Any free library other than POI(Which does record by record copy rather than some bulk way that use less memory)

Comment: ApachePoi can also do this

Comment: How can Apache POI do this please tell @N.Neupane

Comment: No you can provide me the link also from where I can get help because I didn't find it anywhere @N.Neupane

Answer (score 1):

My original idea was to use the cloneSheet method of XSSFWorkbook to do the trick, I was successful in copying the Relations and Drawings however failed to copy the data itself. Why? Because the XSSFSheet's method write and read are protected, I did come up with my own version of XSSFSheet by extending it and making the two methods write and read public, but that would mean I will have to copy and edit every source file using XSSFSheet replacing it with my version of XSSFSheet that would mean too much coding I didn't have that kind of time for the project.

The original answer to this question was posted on:

[How to copy a sheet between Excel workbooks in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13090313/how-to-copy-a-sheet-between-excel-workbooks-in-java)

However, my project requirement were different, so I improvised the answer.

I added a method called combine which accepts target workbook, and source workbook.

The methods loops through all the worksheets in the source workbook and adds them to target workbook. The original answer lacked copying of relations and drawing.

Also the workbooks I was to copy from lacked Footer, neede Gridlines to be turned off, and fit to page. So here is my solution:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocumentPart.RelationPart;
import org.apache.poi.POIXMLException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.PackageRelationship;
import org.apache.poi.openxml4j.opc.TargetMode;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.util.POILogger;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRelation;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.spreadsheetml.x2006.main.CTWorksheet;

import com.hcsc.eas.framework.services.logging.Logger;


public class XSSFWorkbookHelper {
    static protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(XSSFWorkbookHelper.class.getName());  

    public static void combine(XSSFWorkbook tgt, XSSFWorkbook src) throws InvalidFormatException {
        // begin sheets loop
        boolean first=true;
        String firstSheetName = null;
        XSSFSheet tgtSheet = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < src.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
            XSSFSheet srcSheet = src.getSheetAt(i);
            String sheetName = srcSheet.getSheetName().replaceAll("_", "-");
            if (first) {
                firstSheetName = srcSheet.getSheetName();
                if (sheetName.equals(firstSheetName)) sheetName = sheetName + "_";
                first = false;
            } 
            tgtSheet = tgt.createSheet(sheetName);

            copyRelations(tgtSheet, srcSheet);

            copySheets(tgtSheet, srcSheet);
        } // end sheets loop
        tgtSheet = tgt.getSheet(firstSheetName);
        if(tgtSheet != null)   {
            tgt.removeSheetAt(tgt.getSheetIndex(tgtSheet));
        }
    }

    private static void copyRelations(XSSFSheet tgtSheet,XSSFSheet srcSheet) {
        // copy sheet's relations
        List<RelationPart> rels = srcSheet.getRelationParts();
        // if the sheet being cloned has a drawing then rememebr it and re-create it too
        XSSFDrawing dg = null;
        for(RelationPart rp : rels) {
            POIXMLDocumentPart r = rp.getDocumentPart();
            // do not copy the drawing relationship, it will be re-created
            if(r instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
                dg = (XSSFDrawing)r;
                continue;
            }

            addRelation(rp, tgtSheet);
        }

        try {
            for(PackageRelationship pr : srcSheet.getPackagePart().getRelationships()) {
                if (pr.getTargetMode() == TargetMode.EXTERNAL) {
                    tgtSheet.getPackagePart().addExternalRelationship
                        (pr.getTargetURI().toASCIIString(), pr.getRelationshipType(), pr.getId());
                }
            }
        } catch (InvalidFormatException e) {
            throw new POIXMLException("Failed to clone sheet", e);
        }

        CTWorksheet ct = tgtSheet.getCTWorksheet();
        if(ct.isSetLegacyDrawing()) {
            logger.warn(POILogger.WARN + "Cloning sheets with comments is not yet supported.");
            ct.unsetLegacyDrawing();
        }
        if (ct.isSetPageSetup()) {
            logger.warn(POILogger.WARN + "Cloning sheets with page setup is not yet supported.");
            ct.unsetPageSetup();
        }

        tgtSheet.setSelected(false);

        // clone the sheet drawing alongs with its relationships
        if (dg != null) {
            if(ct.isSetDrawing()) {
                // unset the existing reference to the drawing,
                // so that subsequent call of tgtSheet.createDrawingPatriarch() will create a new one
                ct.unsetDrawing();
            }
            XSSFDrawing clonedDg = tgtSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            // copy drawing contents
            clonedDg.getCTDrawing().set(dg.getCTDrawing());

            clonedDg = tgtSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();

            // Clone drawing relations
            List<RelationPart> srcRels = srcSheet.createDrawingPatriarch().getRelationParts();
            for (RelationPart rp : srcRels) {
                addRelation(rp, clonedDg);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void addRelation(RelationPart rp, POIXMLDocumentPart target) {
        PackageRelationship rel = rp.getRelationship();
        if (rel.getTargetMode() == TargetMode.EXTERNAL) {
            target.getPackagePart().addRelationship(rel.getTargetURI(), rel.getTargetMode(), rel.getRelationshipType(),
                    rel.getId());
        } else {
            XSSFRelation xssfRel = XSSFRelation.getInstance(rel.getRelationshipType());
            if (xssfRel == null) {
                // Don't copy all relations blindly, but only the ones we know
                // about
                throw new POIXMLException(
                        "Can't clone sheet - unknown relation type found: " + rel.getRelationshipType());
            }
            target.addRelation(rel.getId(), xssfRel, rp.getDocumentPart());
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param newSheet
     *            the sheet to create from the copy.
     * @param sheet
     *            the sheet to copy.
     */
    public static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet) {
        copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);
    }

    /**
     * @param newSheet
     *            the sheet to create from the copy.
     * @param sheet
     *            the sheet to copy.
     * @param copyStyle
     *            true copy the style.
     */
    public static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle) {
        setupSheet(newSheet);

        int maxColumnNum = 0;
        Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle) ? new HashMap<Integer, CellStyle>() : null;
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
            if (srcRow != null) {
                copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
                if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {
                    maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {
            newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));
        }
    }

    public static void setupSheet(XSSFSheet newSheet) {
        newSheet.getFooter().setCenter("&7 _x0000_ A Division of Health Care Service Corporation, a Mutual Legal Reserve Company, \n _x0000_  an Independent Licensee of the Blue Cross and Blue Shield Association");
        newSheet.setDisplayGridlines(false);
        newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.RightMargin, 0.5 /* inches */ );
        newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin, 0.5 /* inches */ );
        newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.TopMargin, 0.5 /* inches */ );
        newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin, 0.5 /* inches */ );
        newSheet.setFitToPage(true);
    }

    /**
     * @param srcSheet
     *            the sheet to copy.
     * @param destSheet
     *            the sheet to create.
     * @param srcRow
     *            the row to copy.
     * @param destRow
     *            the row to create.
     * @param styleMap
     *            -
     */
    public static void copyRow(XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, XSSFRow destRow,
            Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {
        try {
            // manage a list of merged zone in order to not insert two times a
            // merged zone
            Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddressWrapper>();
            destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
            // reckoning delta rows
            int deltaRows = destRow.getRowNum() - srcRow.getRowNum();
            // pour chaque row
            for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
                XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j); // ancienne cell
                XSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j); // new cell
                if (oldCell != null) {
                    if (newCell == null) {
                        newCell = destRow.createCell(j);
                    }
                    // copy chaque cell
                    copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
                    // copy les informations de fusion entre les cellules
                    // System.out.println("row num: " + srcRow.getRowNum() + " ,
                    // col: " + (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());
                    CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(),
                            (short) oldCell.getColumnIndex());

                    if (mergedRegion != null) {
                        // System.out.println("Selected merged region: " +
                        // mergedRegion.toString());
                        CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow() + deltaRows,
                                mergedRegion.getLastRow() + deltaRows, mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(),
                                mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
                        // System.out.println("New merged region: " +
                        // newMergedRegion.toString());
                        CellRangeAddressWrapper wrapper = new CellRangeAddressWrapper(newMergedRegion);
                        if (isNewMergedRegion(wrapper, mergedRegions)) {
                            mergedRegions.add(wrapper);
                            destSheet.addMergedRegion(wrapper.range);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
            logger.warn(POILogger.WARN + "merge area failure, happens when a merge area overlaps.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param oldCell
     * @param newCell
     * @param styleMap
     */
    public static void copyCell(XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {
        if (styleMap != null) {
            if (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()) {
                newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            } else {
                int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
                CellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
                if (newCellStyle == null) {
                    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                    styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
                }
                newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
            }
        }
        switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
            newCell.setCellType(XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
            break;
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
            break;
        case XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves cell merge information in the source sheet
     * to apply them to the destination sheet ... Get all zones
     * merged in the source sheet and look for each of them if she
     * find in the current row that we are dealing. If yes, return the object
     * CellRangeAddress.
     * 
     * @param sheet
     *            the sheet containing the data.
     * @param rowNum
     *            the num of the row to copy.
     * @param cellNum
     *            the num of the cell to copy.
     * @return the CellRangeAddress created.
     */
    public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
            CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {
                return merged;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     * Check that the merged region has been created in the destination sheet.
     * 
     * @param newMergedRegion
     *            the merged region to copy or not in the destination sheet.
     * @param mergedRegions
     *            the list containing all the merged region.
     * @return true if the merged region is already in the list or not.
     */
    private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddressWrapper newMergedRegion,
            Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions) {
        return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);
    }

}

class CellRangeAddressWrapper implements Comparable<CellRangeAddressWrapper> {

    public CellRangeAddress range;

    /**
     * @param theRange
     *            the CellRangeAddress object to wrap.
     */
    public CellRangeAddressWrapper(CellRangeAddress theRange) {
        this.range = theRange;
    }

    /**
     * @param o
     *            the object to compare.
     * @return -1 the current instance is prior to the object in parameter, 0:
     *         equal, 1: after...
     */
    public int compareTo(CellRangeAddressWrapper o) {

        if (range.getFirstColumn() < o.range.getFirstColumn() && range.getFirstRow() < o.range.getFirstRow()) {
            return -1;
        } else if (range.getFirstColumn() == o.range.getFirstColumn() && range.getFirstRow() == o.range.getFirstRow()) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            return 1;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: do you have code for merging multiple sheets to single sheet too, if yes Please?

Answer (score 1):

This code can be used for merging two excels.
It worked for me:

```
public static void mergeExcels(Workbook sourceExcel, Workbook destExcel) {
    for(int sheetIndex = 0; sheetIndex < sourceExcel.getNumberOfSheets(); ++sheetIndex) {
        Sheet sheet = sourceExcel.getSheetAt(sheetIndex);
        if (destExcel.getSheet(sheet.getSheetName()) != null) {
            destExcel.removeSheetAt(destExcel.getSheetIndex(sheet.getSheetName()));
        }

        Sheet outputSheet = destExcel.createSheet(sheet.getSheetName());
        copySheets(outputSheet, sheet, true);
    }

}

public static void copySheets(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet, boolean copyStyle) {
    int maxColumnNum = 0;
    Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap = copyStyle ? new HashMap() : null;

    int i;
    List<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions = new ArrayList<CellRangeAddress>();
    for(i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); ++i) {
        Row srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);
        Row destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
        if (srcRow != null) {
            copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap, mergedRegions);
            if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {
                maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
            }
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; ++i) {
        newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));
    }

}

public static void copyRow(Sheet srcSheet, Sheet destSheet, Row srcRow, Row destRow, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap, List<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions ) {
    destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());

    for(int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); ++j) {
        if (j >= 0) {
            Cell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
            Cell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);
            if (oldCell != null) {
                if (newCell == null) {
                    newCell = destRow.createCell(j);
                }

                copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
                CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());
                if (mergedRegion != null) {
                    CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow(),  mergedRegion.getLastRow(), mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(), mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
                    if (isNewMergedRegion(newMergedRegion, mergedRegions)) {
                        mergedRegions.add(newMergedRegion);
                        destSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedRegion);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public static void copyCell(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell, Map<Integer, CellStyle> styleMap) {
    if (styleMap != null) {
        if (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()) {
            newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
        } else {
            int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
            CellStyle newCellStyle = (CellStyle)styleMap.get(stHashCode);
            if (newCellStyle == null) {
                newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
            }

            newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
        }
    }

    switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {
        case 0:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
            break;
        case 1:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
            break;
        case 2:
            newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
            break;
        case 3:
            newCell.setCellType(3);
            break;
        case 4:
            newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
            break;
        case 5:
            newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
    }

}

public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(Sheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {
    for(int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); ++i) {
        CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
        if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {
            return merged;
        }
    }

    return null;
}

private static boolean areAllTrue(boolean... values) {
    for(int i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {
        if (!values[i]) {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion, Collection<CellRangeAddress> mergedRegions) {
    boolean isNew = true;
    Iterator i$ = mergedRegions.iterator();

    while(i$.hasNext()) {
        CellRangeAddress add = (CellRangeAddress)i$.next();
        boolean r1 = add.getFirstRow() == newMergedRegion.getFirstRow();
        boolean r2 = add.getLastRow() == newMergedRegion.getLastRow();
        boolean c1 = add.getFirstColumn() == newMergedRegion.getFirstColumn();
        boolean c2 = add.getLastColumn() == newMergedRegion.getLastColumn();
        if (areAllTrue(r1, r2, c1, c2)) {
            isNew = false;
        }
    }

    return isNew;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a copied answer from here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13090315/8106631
, but adjusted for XSSF

```
package com.org.csm.cqoc.controller;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellType;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
 
/**
 *
 * @author jk
 * getted from http://jxls.cvs.sourceforge.net/jxls/jxls/src/java/org/jxls/util/Util.java?revision=1.8&view=markup
 * by Leonid Vysochyn 
 * and modified (adding styles copying)
 * modified 21.10.2021 for XSSF
 */
public class UtilExcel {
    public static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet){
        copySheets(newSheet, sheet, true);
    }
    public static void copySheets(XSSFSheet newSheet, XSSFSheet sheet, boolean copyStyle){
        int maxColumnNum = 0;
        Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap = (copyStyle)
                ? new HashMap<Integer, XSSFCellStyle>() : null;
 
        for (int i = sheet.getFirstRowNum(); i <= sheet.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
            XSSFRow srcRow = sheet.getRow(i);
            XSSFRow destRow = newSheet.createRow(i);
            if (srcRow != null) {
                UtilExcel.copyRow(sheet, newSheet, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
                if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {
                    maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {
            newSheet.setColumnWidth(i, sheet.getColumnWidth(i));
        }
        
    }
 
    public static void copyRow(XSSFSheet srcSheet, XSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, XSSFRow destRow, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {
        destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
        for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
            XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j);
            XSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j);
            if (oldCell != null) {
                if (newCell == null) {
                    newCell = destRow.createCell(j);
                }
                copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
                CellRangeAddress mergedCellRangeAddress = getMergedCellRangeAddress(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(), oldCell.getColumnIndex());
                if (mergedCellRangeAddress != null) {
                    CellRangeAddress newMergedCellRangeAddress = new CellRangeAddress(mergedCellRangeAddress.getFirstRow(), mergedCellRangeAddress.getLastRow(),
                            mergedCellRangeAddress.getFirstColumn(), mergedCellRangeAddress.getLastColumn());
                    if (!destSheet.getMergedRegions().contains(newMergedCellRangeAddress)) {
                        destSheet.addMergedRegion(newMergedCellRangeAddress);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
         
    }
    public static void copyCell(XSSFCell oldCell, XSSFCell newCell, Map<Integer, XSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {
        if(styleMap != null) {
            if(oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()){
                newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
            } else{
                int stHashCode = oldCell.getCellStyle().hashCode();
                XSSFCellStyle newCellStyle = styleMap.get(stHashCode);
                if(newCellStyle == null){
                    newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
                    newCellStyle.cloneStyleFrom(oldCell.getCellStyle());
                    styleMap.put(stHashCode, newCellStyle);
                }
                newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
            }
        }
        switch(oldCell.getCellType()) {
            case STRING:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
                break;
            case NUMERIC:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
                break;
            case BLANK:
                newCell.setCellType(CellType.BLANK);
                break;
            case BOOLEAN:
                newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
                break;
            case ERROR:
                newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
                break;
            case FORMULA:
                newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
         
    }
    public static CellRangeAddress getMergedCellRangeAddress(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, int cellNum) {
        for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getMergedRegions().size(); i++) {
            CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
            if (merged.containsColumn(cellNum) && merged.containsRow(rowNum)) {
                return merged;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
 
}
```

Comment: "This is a copied answer" That's not authorized to copy answer. Please do your own or upvote other answer

Comment: just wanted to share what i found..... !!!!

Comment: Which answer did you copy ? It's better to link the founded answer, to make it always up-to-date with the source

Comment: @Elikill58 The license does allow copying answers, as long as there is an attribution to the original.