# Copying of two different excel sheets to one sheet using Java

Tags: java, excel

## Copying of two different excel sheets to one new excel sheet using Java code is resulting in partial output.

#### This is for Java code running in IntelliJ, using Apache POI.

```
public static void copySheet(XSSFSheet inputSheet1, XSSFSheet outputSheet, XSSFSheet inputSheet2)

    {
        int rowCount = inputSheet1.getLastRowNum();
        int rc = inputSheet2.getLastRowNum(),rcnt=0,cri =0,l=0;
        int currentRowIndex = 0, cell = 0;
        if (rowCount > 0) {
            Iterator rowIterator = inputSheet1.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                int currentCellIndex = 0;
                Iterator cellIterator;
                Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
                    //Creating new Row, Cell and Input value in the newly created sheet.
                    String cellData = cellIterator.next().toString();
                    if (currentCellIndex == 0)
                        outputSheet.createRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                    else
                        outputSheet.getRow(currentRowIndex).createCell(currentCellIndex).setCellValue(cellData);
                    currentCellIndex++;
                    System.out.println("content test2 " + cellData);
                    System.out.println("current row index  " + currentRowIndex);
                    System.out.println("current cell   " + cell);
                }
                currentRowIndex++;
                cell = currentCellIndex;
                rcnt = cell;
            }
        }
        cri = 0;
        if (rc > 0) {
            Iterator rowIterator = inputSheet2.iterator();
            while (rowIterator.hasNext()) {
                int currentCellIndex2 = 0,cci = rcnt+1;
                Iterator cellIterator2;
                Row row = (Row) rowIterator.next();
                cellIterator2 = row.cellIterator();
                while (cellIterator2.hasNext()) {
                    
                    String cellData = cellIterator2.next().toString();

                    if (currentCellIndex2 == 0)
                        outputSheet.createRow(cri).createCell(cci).setCellValue(cellData);
                    else
                        outputSheet.getRow(cri).createCell(cci).setCellValue(cellData);
                    currentCellIndex2 = currentCellIndex2+1;
                    cci = cci +1;
                    System.out.println("content "+cellData);
                    System.out.println("current row index  " + cri);
                }
                cri++;
            }
        }
}
```

**Expected output** :

both the sheets should be copied to the new sheet.

**Actual output** :

only the second input sheet is copied to the new sheet.
If I try to copy one the first sheet it will be copied. But if I try to copy both only second sheet will be present.

**Input_one**

[image: input_one]

**Input_two**

[image: input_2]

**Output**

[image: output]

Comment: Hi, looks like there are some solutions  [Merging Two excel files as two sheets in one workbook in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575759/merging-two-excel-files-as-two-sheets-in-one-workbook-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are overwriting output of the first `while` loop with the output of the second because in one you use `currentRowIndex` and in the second you use `cri`. Reuse the `currentRowIndex` for the second while-loop as well, so that the rows from the second sheet get appended after the ones for the first one.