# How to merge multiple excel files into single excel file using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have multiple excel files in a specific location where in each excel file might have 2 sheets in it.

For example, two excel files at location 
/disk2/example/ames/sample1.xlsx which has 2 sheets(sheet names as, s1 and s2) in it and
/disk2/example/ames/sample2.xlsx has 1 sheet(sheet name as s3) in it.

I want to create a new xlsx file in the path /disk2/example/ames/sampleMerged.xlsx which should have all the 3 sheets s1, s2 and s3 in it by merging sample1 and sample2 files.

Is there a best way to merge multiple spreadsheets into single Excel file with multiple tabs, only using Apache poi or any open/free source libraries?

**P.S: Would Not prefer Aspose library for it.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging Two excel files as two sheets in one workbook in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21575759/merging-two-excel-files-as-two-sheets-in-one-workbook-in-java)

Comment: @Im_Pratik thanks much. However, the solutions don't solve my issue though.

Comment: I think you have to create a new workbook, open your first file, get the Sheet and set it to the workboox created by yourself and do the same thing for the second sheet of your second excel

Comment: @Fizik26 could you help me out with a sample code. Thanks!